# Lorentz transformation of the Dirac function

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, dirac-delta-distributions

Consider a Lorentz transformation that takes the $(x, y, z, t)$ coordinates of a point in Minkowski space into $(x', y', z', t')$. An electrically charged object at rest in the first reference frame has an electric charge density $\rho$, while in the second reference frame the electric charge density is $\rho' = \gamma(v) \rho$. When the object collapses into a material point at the origin, at $t = t'= 0$, $\rho(x, y, z) = e \delta^3(x, y, z)$ and $\rho'(x', y', z') = e \delta^3(x', y', z')$, where $e$ is the charge of the electron. It seems that $\delta^3(x', y', z') = \gamma(v) \delta^3(x, y, z)$. For a boost in the $x$ direction, $\delta(x') = \gamma(v) \delta(x)$. This equation doesn't seem to come out of the rule for $\delta(f(x))$. From $x'= \gamma(v) (x - v t)$ I get $\delta(x'(x)) = \delta(x - vt)/\gamma(v) => \delta(x)/\gamma(v)$ when t = 0. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You have to be careful here, because $\delta (x')$ is not merely a function of $x$.  When you write down the expression

$$e = \int d^3 r\  e \delta(x)\delta(y)\delta(z)$$

you are taking a slice of spacetime (e.g. $t=t_0$) and then integrating $\rho$ over that slice.  If you boost to a different reference frame, then the slice over which you are integrating will **not** be characterized by constant $t'$. Upon transforming coordinates
$$x' = \gamma(x-vt) \implies x = \gamma(x'+vt')$$
$$y'=y$$
$$z'=z$$
$$t'=\gamma\left(t - \frac{vx}{c^2}\right)\implies t = \gamma\left(t' +\frac{vx'}{c^2}\right)$$

we see that the slice $t=0$ corresponds to the slice $t' =- \gamma\frac{vx'}{c^2}$.  Correspondingly,

$$x = \gamma(x'+vt') = \gamma\left(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}\right)x'= \frac{x'}{\gamma}$$

which means that $\delta (x) = \delta\left(\frac{x'}{\gamma}\right) = \gamma \delta(x')$.